# How to access element (Combo Box) in XAML from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

How do I access a control in XAML that is nested in a `GridViewColumn.CellTemplate`? By accessing the combo box I want to set its `ItemsSource` in the code behind.

Code:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="80">
    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="UseCLUT"/>
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=UseCLUT}" Style="{StaticResource GridBlockStyle}"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="combTrueFalse" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=UseCLUT}" Style="{StaticResource GridEditStyle}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

I have named the comboBox as combTrueFalse and tried to referenced it in the code behind but it could not be found.

Comment: Will the items be changing in the combobox or just static items

Comment: I don't have the answer but can tell you why you cannot access it in code behind. That's because this combo is not in the main control but is part of a datatemplate of `GridViewColumn`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF How to access control from DataTemplate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586106/wpf-how-to-access-control-from-datatemplate)

Comment: sa_ddam213 - The item in the combobox will be binded to collection of data so its not static. Also i tried to set the TEXT property to a static value but nth is showing any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a work around to the problem.

I have set the collection of the combo box to a class which contains the collection for the combox's selection.

The mainWindow class contains the data class's variable.

```
 ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow, Path=data.comboxTFSmall}"
```

Meaning to say I have set the combox's item towards a Class which contains the collection and not from the code behind.

```
 <GridViewColumn Width="80" >
                                <GridViewColumnHeader Content="UseCLUT"/>
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=UseCLUT, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource GridBlockStyle}"/>
                                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow, Path=data.comboxTFSmall}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=UseCLUT}" Style="{StaticResource GridEditStyle}" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
```

Please do correct me if you find that my explanation is misleading thanks.

regards