# Accessing DataGrid from DataTemplate (silverlight)

Tags: .net, silverlight, datagrid, datatemplate

[WPF How to access control from DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586106/wpf-how-to-access-control-from-datatemplate)

In above example, the answers are all related to .Net solution. I am looking for similar solution for silverlight, it does not have FindName on Framework Template. My DataTemplate has a grid which I need to use to open the selecteditem on the grid. I currently have 4 grids which are placed using contentpresenter and since Silverlight does not support TemplateSelector I have visibility set to hide and show correct content presenter. 
Is there a way I can access Grid within my data template?

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultTemplate">
            <toolkit:DataGrid x:Name="dgGrid" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding List}" 
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                              HeadersVisibility="Column"
                              ColumnHeaderHeight="30" 
                              VerticalGridLinesBrush="Transparent"
                              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                              SelectionMode="Single"
                              RowStyle="{StaticResource rowStyle}" 
                              FontSize="16" 
                              IsReadOnly="True">
                <toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
                    <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" SortMemberPath="IsInvalid" >
                        <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="!" Visibility="{Binding IsInvalid, Converter={StaticResource conv}}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <!--Open Button-->
                    <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="70">
                        <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Content="Open"
                                    Width="60"
                                    FontSize="14"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    Margin="0"  
                                    Click="Open_Click"
                                    />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="150" FontSize="18" Binding="{Binding CustomerName}" />


                </toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
            </toolkit:DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

I am trying to access dgGrid on above DataTemplate

Updated:

In my control I have following

```
<StackPanel>

        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Template1}" Visibility="{Binding PanelID,Converter={StaticResource ParamVisibilityConv}, ConverterParameter=5}"/>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Template2}" Visibility="{Binding PanelID,Converter={StaticResource ParamVisibilityConv}, ConverterParameter=7}"/>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding}"  ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Template3}" Visibility="{Binding PanelID,Converter={StaticResource ParamVisibilityConv}, ConverterParameter=13}"/>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding}"  ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}" Visibility="{Binding PanelID,Converter={StaticResource ParamVisibilityConv}, ConverterParameter=4}"/>

</StackPanel>
```

I am trying to access the grid in code behind

```
StackPanel sp = (StackPanel) this.Content;
            foreach (var child in sp.Children)
            {
                if (child is ContentPresenter && ((ContentPresenter) child).Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
                {
                    DataTemplate dt = ((ContentPresenter) child).ContentTemplate;
                }
            }
```

it returns a DataTemplate but FrameworkTemplates dont have FindName function to find elements within a DataTemplate.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding your DataTemplate you have to load whatever is inside it.
For Example:

```
var grid = dt.LoadContent() as DataGrid/StackPanel/AnyElement;
```

Once you loaded the element you can use System.Linq assembly to perform high level queries within it.

For Example:

```
var item = grid.Children.First(c => c.Name == "element1");
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was not able to test this out. I ended up creating a whole new control with some duplicated code. Nonetheless, Thanks!