# How to add WPF DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate ComboBox itemsource at back-end

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox, wpfdatagrid

I would like to add my DataTable return data to my DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate combobox, But the combo box is empty

My xaml code as follow

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Student">
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate >
      <DataTemplate>
           <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding dtStudent}"    DisplayMemberPath="StudentName"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Back-End

```
dtStudent = new Function().Sel_Student(); //Function that return student detail
```

I try to add a Name for the combobox control , but it is not accessible from the back-end .

Is my binding method wrong or do I have other method to achieving what I need

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to access the control by its name when it is defined in DataTemplate. You can get the ComboBox from its visual tree.
Please refer this [WPF How to access control from DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586106/wpf-how-to-access-control-from-datatemplate)

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind to a property and not to a function. So in your back end you should have

```
public IEnumerable<Student> Students
{
    get
    {
        return Sel_Students();
    }
}

private IEnumerable<Student> Sel_Students()
{
    return { ... your students};
}

public class Student {
}
```